# Meridians and Parallels on a Unit Sphere

Tags: surfaces, curves, parametrization

Let $S$ be the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^3$ with centre $(0, 0, 0)$

$\sigma(u, v) = (\cos v/\cosh u,\sin v/\cosh u,\tanh u)$

is a parametrization of $S$ minus the north and south poles.

Show that meridians and parallels on $S$ correspond under $\sigma$ to perpendicular straight lines in the plane with coordinates $(u, v)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question ?